# Does There Exist a Term for the Unique Nonpositive Square Root of a Nonnegative Real Number?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The term "principal square root" describes the unique nonnegative square root of a nonnegative real number.

Does there exist a term to describe the unique nonpositive square root of a nonnegative real number?

Comment: It's not commonly used... so I guess not.

Comment: Very honestly, I have never heard of your second term. By definition, the squareroot of 16 is 4. However, x² = 16 has two solutions, 4 and -4 and for that reason it is sometimes said that the roots of 16 are 4 and -4, but I am not an advocate of such language. Similarly, when they talk about the cuberoots of, say i, it is meant to find the three solutions to x^3 = i  The notation cuberoot(i) by itself was a reason for my professor to knock off a point from the exam...

Comment: @imranfat I suggest you remind yourself of the definition of the term "squareroot".  The term "the squareroot" is a different term, but as far as I can tell it depends on the definition of the term "squareroot".  I do agree that talking about the roots of 16 as 4 and -4 makes no sense, but I think it does make sense to talk about the set of roots of 16 as {4, -4}.

Comment: I can agree on the "sets of roots" having 3 answers for x^3 = i. In fact, I like your terminology! I think I will use that in future. But the notation √i for example is meaningless, and as I stated, we were taken off points (yes, it happened to me) for silly notations like that. (Didn't study in USA, if that matters, so quoting my literature is useless)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have heard "negative square root."  It's about the simplest and most aptly descriptive thing I have heard.

Comment: Shouldn't there be "of" between "negative" and "root"?

Comment: you would say "negative square root of 5" for $-\sqrt{5}.$